# Macro to get values of last column to new sheet

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a Macro to get the values of the last column (in my case column R) of each sheet into a new sheet named "MainSheet"

If there are 4 sheets the last column values should be fetched to the mainsheet columns A, B, C & D

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is column `R` always your last column in each sheet or does it vary?

Comment: column R is always last column in each sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data always starts in `A1` on each of the sheets that you want to copy from then this may get you started:

```
Sub CopyLastColumns()
    Dim cnt As Integer, sht As Worksheet, mainsht As Worksheet, col As Integer, rw As Integer

    Set mainsht = Worksheets("MainSheet")

    cnt = 1
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> "MainSheet" Then
            sht.Columns(sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count).Copy
            mainsht.Columns(cnt).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            mainsht.Cells(10, cnt) = sht.Range("A2") 
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next sht

    With mainsht
        For col = 1 To cnt
            For rw = .Cells(65536, col).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
                If .Cells(rw, col) = "" Then
                    .Cells(rw, col).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                End If
            Next rw
        Next col
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,this works perfect, But the column R has merged cells in every sheet and the merged cells are in range from (R2:R25), (R26:R49), (R50:R73), (R74:R97), (R98:R121), (R122:R145), (R146:R169)
This is constant in every sheet, When I run the Script because of the merged cells the values not coming in subsequent rows
Any way to get the values successively without the merged cells in between?

Comment: @user1292831 - See updated code. I have added a loop to remove empty cells on `MainSheet`. I think this gives you what you need.

Comment: This is just what I want :D , I also want to get the value of cell A2 which is a name in each sheet and get this data in A10, B10, C10, D10.. cells of the MainSheet
If there are 4 sheets, A2 values from the 4 sheets should be fetched to A10, B10, C10, D10 in the MainSheet

Comment: Is there any way that the data fetched to the main sheet be shifted by 1 column i.e starting from column B leaving the column A empty

Comment: Can you also help me to get the value of cell A2 which is a name in each sheet and get this data in A10, B10, C10, D10.. cells of the MainSheet If there are 4 sheets, A2 values from the 4 sheets should be fetched to A10, B10, C10, D10 in the MainSheet

Comment: @user1292831 - See additional line in code above. Does this work?

Comment: When executed, the values from A2 in all the sheets 1st going to A10, B10...because of the merged cells shifting up these values in A10, B10... are getting mixed up with the data from the last columns

Comment: And the same result if I want to get in Horizontal way instead of vertical, how should I modify the code?